# Mission Control behaving differently with monitor plugged in

Tags: macos, display, spaces, mission-control

On OSX 10.9 (maybe other versions, too), I've noticed that the icons for the different spaces in Mission Control behave differently whether or not I have a monitor plugged in.

With a monitor plugged in, the label is always there and there is no magnification effect on hover.

Without a monitor, the labels are only there on hover and there's a magnification effect reminiscent of the dock.

Do you know if there's a way to make it always act like it does when there's a monitor plugged in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to the differing amount of spaces shown in Mission Control, and both situations can be re-created with independently of the quantity of displays.

---

When you have a small number of spaces, it shows like this:

[image: 4 Spaces]

When you have lots of spaces, it shows like this:

[image: 8 Spaces]

This is not due to the number of displays you have connected but rather simply the number of spaces you have open.

To recreate…

- You can make it act like the first example by having a small number of spaces, and it will use the default size and show the name of the space.
- You can make it act like the second example by having a lot of open spaces, and it will reduce the size of the space thumbnails to fit them on, and hide the space name if necessary.